# Convert MongoDB query into Spring Repository

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I'm unable to convert the following mongoDB query into spring query. I want add this query to my repository (by using annotation @Query) and then use this in my controller... This is query in mongoDB:

```
db.campaignsForChatUsers.aggregate([{ $group: {_id : "_id", avgTime: { $avg : "$details.nostradamusOfferCalculatingTime"}}}])
```

What I should add to `@Query(value = "...")` ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Query from Spring-data-mongodb only supports find()- method, it doesn't support aggregations. You have to write aggregations using your own implementation.

Comment: @Lucia ok. Thanks.